# Eilenberg Steenrod axioms of homology not a natural transformation?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, functors

According to wikipedia, an ordinary homology theory (in the sense of Eilenberg - Steenrod) is a sequence of functors $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}: \text{Pairs} \rightarrow \text{Ab}$ where $\text{Pairs}$ is the category where objects are pairs of topogical spaces $(X,A)$ s.t. $A \subseteq X$ and $\text{Ab}$ is the category of abelian groups, together with a natural transformation $\partial: h_n (X,A) \rightarrow h_{n-1}(A,\emptyset)$.

**In what sense is $\partial$ a natural transformation?**

(Also according to wikipedia) a natural transformation $\alpha$ between two functors $F,G: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are categories is a family of morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ indexed by the objects in $\mathcal{C}$ s.t. $\alpha_c: F(c) \rightarrow G(c)$ where $c$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$.

However, in the definition of axiomatic homology, we consider $\alpha: F(c) \rightarrow G(c')$ for $c \neq c'$. Why is that?

Comment: Are you asking for a definition of *natural transformation*?  Or are you asking how boundary maps as appearing in a particular homology theory are indeed natural transformations?

Comment: The latter. I am asking how what is given on wikipedia defines a natural transformation $h_n \rightarrow h_{n-1}$

Comment: Both $h_n(X,A)$ and $h_{n-1}(A,\emptyset)$ are functors of topological pairs $(X,A)$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ I am given two functors? One being $h_n: (X,A) \mapsto h_n(X,A)$ and the other as $h_n: (X,A) \mapsto h_n(A, \emptyset)$?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't call the second one $h_n$ too!

Comment: @AnginaSeng $h_n(X,A)$, and $h_{n-1}(A,\emptyset)$ are the *values* of functors, not actually functors.

Comment: There is a functor $Pairs\xrightarrow{\kappa} Pairs$ which sends $(X,A)$ to $(A,\emptyset)$ and a map of pairs to its restriction. The natural transformation $\Delta$ is one between the functors $h_n$ and $h_{n-1}\circ\kappa$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tyrone remarked in his comment, we have the "restriction functor" $R : \operatorname{Pairs} \to \operatorname{Pairs}$ given by $R(X,A) = (A,\emptyset)$ and $R(f) )= f\mid_A :  (A,\emptyset) \to  (B,\emptyset)$ for $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$. Then $$\partial_n : h_n \to h_{n-1} \circ R$$
is a natural transformation between the functors $h_n :  \operatorname{Pairs} \to \operatorname{Ab}$ and $h_{n-1} \circ R :  \operatorname{Pairs} \to \operatorname{Ab}$.